# Piping unique lines in bash in real time

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

I have a very long running process that writes a few events to stdout.
For example, a possible output after a long time of execution would be:

```
event1
event2
event5
event1
event5
event3
event1
```

I want to process each unique event once only, i.e. if event1 has already taken place, I want to skip every other occurrence of event1. In the given example that would be:

```
event1
event2
event5
event3
```

I need to process each event as soon as it takes place, so I need to avoid blocking until the output is complete and avoid buffered output.

I have already tried this:

- `my_program | sort | uniq`
  This blocks until end of execution of my_program because sort should block until all output is ready
- `my_program | awk '!x[$0]++'`
  I don't know why this blocks until end of execution of my_program
- `my_program | mawk '!x[$0]++'`
  I don't know why this blocks until end of execution of my_program

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: I don’t know if there are exlusive ways to do it in bash, but in languages like C, you either need to use locks or atomic instructions. The best way i believe it can be done declare a gloabal array and keep logging events that have occured in it and before every occurence of even just place a check like `[ -z “${arr[$event]}”] && <execute event>`.

Comment: You want to make sure that both `my_program` and `awk` are using unbuffered output, so that both programs actually write to their output file once it determines  a line should be output.

Comment: @chepner can you possibly post an answer showing how it is done? It would be helpful to me as well.

Comment: Try running your program under `stdbuf` and piping into `awk`... https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html

Comment: Or if your process is Python, start with `python -u` for unbuffered output.

Comment: The `expect` package includes a script called `unbuffer` which may be useful. Also take a look at `fflush()` in AWK.